# FATAL: Couldn’t find any executable in /usr/share/maven/bin/

Tags: maven, jenkins

i am getting below error while trying to clean package.

FATAL:

> Couldn’t find any executable in /usr/share/maven/bin/ i have set
>   /usr/share/maven/bin/ as my MAVEN_HOME

Comment: MAVEN_HOME should point to installed dir not bin , your path variable should point to maven bin

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Make sure there is mvn shell/command prompt file in the targeted location. If not , then re-install Maven and reset the **MAVEN_HOME** path in Manage Jenkins -> Global Tools Configuration.

Comment: Thanks , i am able to build package now

Comment: i hav einstalled odcker in my ubuntu machine.biswajeet2@biswajeet2-VirtualBox:~$ sudo adduser docker
[sudo] password for biswajeet2: 
adduser: The group `docker' already exists.
biswajeet2@biswajeet2-VirtualBox:~$ su docker
No passwd entry for user 'docker'

Comment: but while trying to reset the password for user docker i am getting above error

Answer (score 0):

If you are getting the same issue while trying to do build job in Jenkins make sure in the Build Environment tab your build goals and other parameters are set properly.